# Trying to use turf js in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-cli, turfjs

I'm an angular 5 (and turfjs) noob trying to use the turfjs along().

I've got a pretty simple working angular 5 project (built with angular-cli).

To add turf I ran:

```
npm install @turf/along --save
```

and I see @turf/along in my node modules directory.  I tried just adding to my js file:

```
declare var along: any;
```

but that didn't work.  I also tried adding

```
"../node_modules/@turf/along/index.js"
```

to my angular-cli.json file, but no luck.

What is the correct way to import this method so I can use it?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, (eventually) I discovered that I can just use

```
import along from '@turf/along';
```

No declarations or need to mess with other files (e.g. angular-cli.json) and I use it just as if it was defined locally.

If there is a more "TypeScript" way to do this, please drop a comment.

Comment: `import * as turf from '@turf/turf';
...
const lineGeoJson = turf.lineString(myLatLongArray);
const smoothedLine = turf.bezier(lineGeoJson);`